# How create blur gradient?

Tags: flutter, gradient, blur

I have created a blur effect in Flutter on the bottom tool bar of a scroll list. For this I used BackdropFilter with ImageFilter.blur().

The effect looks nice but I don't like the hard edge between the blurred and non-blurred area. I'd like a gradual transition between sharp and blurred.

I noticed that on the bottom of the screen this effect is somehow already there, you can read the number (see picture below, iPhone 11 sim). Seems to be some bug.

I've tried lots of stuff, anyone any idea on how to create this effect on the top edge?

[image: flutter blur example]